# How to work with long time operation using MassTransit?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit and Azure Service Bus as transport.
How I can work with long time operations(from 1 to 18 hours) сonsidering lock timeout of Azure Service Bus?

Comment: If possible, I would instead recommend breaking up your long time operation into smaller chunks, and orchestrate their execution by sending more messages on the bus.

Comment: @SlavaAsipenko I'm talking about consumer(subscriber). It do not need to send something,

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am saying your current consumer/subscriber, upon receiving a message for that long running operation. Instead of starting the work immediately, it will break up the work, and send additional, more granular messages. Which specific subscribers will receive and act on.

Comment: +1 to what @SlavaAsipenko said. You should not renew lock on a message for such an extended time. It indicates that something is off with the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Turnout, but it isn't feature complete yet. It's useful, but the full recovery and exception handling isn't done.

http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/advanced/turnout.html